# Apple Linker Warning "ld: warning: -undefined error is deprecated"

Tags: c++, macos, ld

Currently seeing this linker warning in our C++ builds for macOS:

```
[build] [430/431  99% :: 9.484] Linking CXX executable foobar
[build] ld: warning: -undefined error is deprecated
```

We set this linker option in our `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_link_options("-Wl,-undefined,error")
```

The man page for the `ld` linker also isn't providing useful information either:

```
-undefined treatment
    Specifies how undefined symbols are to be treated. Options are: error, warning, suppress,
    or dynamic_lookup.  The default is error. Note: dynamic_lookup that depends on lazy binding
    will not work with chained fixups.
```

I'm unclear on why this has become deprecated and the action I'm supposed to take.

Comment: XCode 15 includes a completely new linker implementation. Hence some flags are deprecated. *The default is error* - you can simply cancel this explicit flag setup.

Comment: Thanks @273K that fixes my problem and simplifies my CMake code. If you make this comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode 15 includes a completely new [linker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15-release-notes#Linking) implementation. Hence some flags are deprecated.

> And projects build faster thanks to improvements in the compiler and **a brand-new linker**, optimized for the multicore architecture of Apple silicon.

As you referenced in the ld manual, the default treatment for `-undefined` is `error` - you can simply cancel this explicit flag setup in cmake.

Also keep in mind that you still can  explicitly request the old/classic linker with the flag `-ld64`.